# Node API Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, loopbackjs, restify

I have a server side API written in Java that provides all the dynamic data for my web application. I am writing a new front end with Ember.js. I want to create a new back end using Javascript that uses the old API for dynamic data. Basically middleware. I have a big JSON file that contains the information for every page (title, description, URL to get the dynamic data from, etc).

```
website: {
  tab1: {
    title: "Tab 1",
    pages: [
      page1: {
        title: "Page 1",
        description: "Description 1",
        url: "url containing data"
      },
      page2: {
        title: "Page 2",
        description: "Description 2",
        url: "url containing data"
      }
    ]
  },
  tab2: {
    title: "Tab 1",
    pages: [
      page1: {
        title: "Page 1",
        description: "Description 1",
        url: "url containing data"
      },
      page2: {
        title: "Page 2",
        description: "Description 2",
        url: "url containing data"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I make a request to `http://server/` I want to receive `["Tab 1", "Tab 2"]`.

When I make a request to `http://server/tab1` I want to receive `["Page1", "Page 2"]`.

When I make a request to `http://server/tab1/page1` I want to receive `{title: "Page 1", description: "Description 1", data: {DATA FROM URL PROCESSED INTO JSON}}`.

What server side framework would work best for this? There is no database and no changing of the JSON file. There are update/create requests to the API but the middleware will just change the format of the request and pass it to the old API. I hope to one day expand the middleware API to replace the old one completely so I would like a framework instead of writing it all myself as the framework will be easier later on. I have never used REST API frameworks so any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily implement this using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) by defining the routes you need.

One approach would be to load the JSON file when Express starts up and use the route parameters to dynamically fetch the pieces you want from the JSON. If the JSON is huge and you can't fit in memory then I would use a DB instead. But you said 100's of pages which doesn't seem much

Then, in your route handlers, you would filter the JSON object based on the route parameters. For example:

```
app.get('/:tab/:subtab/:page/:resource/:etc', function(request, response, next) {
 var tab = request.params.tab;
 var page = request.params.page;

 // Write a filter() function that extract JSON using tab and page...
 var json = filter(tab, page); 
 return response.send(json);
});
```

Here is the guide to Express routing:
http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: I have 100's of pages so I really don't want to have to create routes for each one. That's why I just want to use a static JSON file. Whatever the requested URL is, the server returns either the titles of the pages under it, or the data if it has a url. Is it possible to create a single route for every url in Express?

Comment: No, you don't need to create a route for each page. Use route parameters instead. One approach would be to load the JSON file when Express starts up and use the route parameters to dynamically fetch the pieces you want from the JSON. If the JSON is huge and you can't fit in memory then I would use a DB instead. But you said 100's of pages which doesn't seem much.

Comment: There are also about 7 layers of tabs/subpages. So in Ember a url would be /tab1/subtab1/page1/resource1/file1. Resource1 and file1 are passed into the server url to return the data to fill a table. While I have hundreds of pages, I only have about 20 types of pages. So I plan to create the handlebars templates for each type of page in Ember and the JSON file will tell ember what template to use. But the number of parts in the url can vary between pages. I don't see how to do varying number of route parameters.

Comment: Yeah, that should work. Every piece of the route  /tab1/subtab1/page1/resource1/file1 can be a parameter so you just have one route that accepts any value you pass to it.  Please mark this answer as accepted ;) Good luck!